# Portfolio Timeline source

Tags: rally

It does not look like the source to the Portfolio Timeline app is on github, though other apps, like Portfolio Kanban are posted there.

Are there plans to release the source for Portfolio Timeline?  If not, what's the hold up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Portfolio Item Timeline uses some JS libraries/functionality around the Gantt charting that are not available/exposed to the AppSDK2 framework (which uses Highcharts). It's not inconceivable that a purely SDK-based version of this App might be released in the future with access to source, however, I don't have a good idea as to when or if that might happen - it's not on the backlog at present.

Comment: Thanks-- I would definitely put my vote in for getting source.  We would love to riff on this app.